# How to replicate password hash for provided password and salt (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, password-hash

Password needs to be matched by Password Hash which was originally created on a .NET platform and stored on MSSQL (so encryption is probably SHA1).

Here is how MySQL table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserName` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PasswordHash` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `PasswordSalt` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=12535 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `UserName`, `PasswordHash`, `PasswordSalt`) VALUES(9836, 'demoadmin', '?z1??9t|????e&??9aK', -1190254076);
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `UserName`, `PasswordHash`, `PasswordSalt`) VALUES(12534, 'sunny', '??o\\(R?8~??6>?t????o', 549612932);
```

I've found two very close examples to what I need to be done but I was enable to make it work.

Example 1: http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/replicating-net-password-hashing-in-php/

Example 2: http://www.kevinbruce.com/Blog?area_id=6&blog_id=3&ba_id=27

Usernames and passwords are:

First user: demoadmin/demotest
Second user: sunny/eclyptix

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an encoding problem:

```
'?z1??9t|????e&??9aK'
```

It seems that your original code was broken and was converting characters out of the printable ASCII range into question marks.

You *could* try to replicate this behaviour in PHP. However continuing to use this broken scheme will compromise the security of your system as it is much more likely that a hash collision can be found. It might be necessary to get all your users to change their passwords. This time make sure that the hashes are stored correctly. You may also want to consider storing them as hexadecimal strings instead of binary data to minimize the risk of further encoding problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark, I agree with you. However I need to make this work as is if possible as we have a legacy database with lot of users.

This is how they are originally stored in SQL Server 2008 database (I would say they are stored in a binary format) and we need to copy them in MySQL database and make it work with PHP. From that point we can encode them to HEX strings and improve things.

Comment: @crazyhorse: If you are lucky, the data was stored correctly in SQL Server, and you just exported/imported incorrectly.

Comment: unfortunately it's exactly the same situation on a SQL Server production server as well.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Bruce here (from the second example you cited).

For what it's worth, I never got the problem solved with my experience. I actually spoke with Elizabeth Smith (who works on PHP core for Windows) and she agreed that there is a big disconnect in hash support on the same level as .NET, due to character encoding support in PHP. This is what I suspected.